# Refactor Button is Grayed Out in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My android studion was working fine. But suddenly I can't refactor any of my projects. When I got to the Refactor->rename then the Button Grayed.

[image]

I tried re-installing android studio but did not work. Then I updated it to the latest version (From 173.4720617 to Build# AI-173.4819257) but got the same problem.

Even I tried to refactor different projects on another pc but got the same problem.

I don't know how this problem is generated within a night to all of my pc's.

Please help me solving this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button is disabled because you are not changing the package name. Try to change the package name to different text, this will enable the button automatically.